# RSolr::Error::Http (RSolr::Error::Http - 429

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, websolr, http-status-code-429

I am working on Ruby on Rails project hosted on heroku server. the search functionnalit works fine on localhost. But when i try on production i get the following error:

```
RSolr::Error::Http (RSolr::Error::Http - 429 
Error: {"code":429,"message":"Request meter exhausted. Please consider batching your requests, or contact support@websolr.com for help."}
```

I have spent time looking for resolving this problem. I found that the 429 code status refers to too many requests in websolr and it is used to protect from DoS attacks.

Please how can I resolve this issue.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websolr Support here. An HTTP 429 response indicates that the connection pool to your index is fully saturated. There are a couple of options to address it:

1. Batch updates. If you're making a lot of single-document writes for some reason, try batching them to reduce the number of connections in use.
2. Upgrade to a higher plan. Concurrency limits scale with plan level, so upgrading can get you the resources you need.
3. Shoot us an email at support@websolr.com and we'll take a look and see if there are any other recommendations.

Comment: Thanks @Rob. this issue was posted while waiting for the email answer. it was fixed once i had contacted you.

Comment: @Rob - if it happens does it mean the affected records didn't get into the index? Should I reindex after solving this issue??

Comment: @Jared Yes, a 429 means the request was rejected. Reindexing the document/batch would ensure it makes its way into the index.